# The Acid Chain Rap

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> I am an acid, found in all of your friends.
>   I tell you how to look, but I don't make amends.
>
> My man named Fred, he told you who I am.
>   But no one understood me until I had an exam!
>
> I've only got one vowel to my name, for sure.
>   But write me out the long way and you'll find a lot more.
>
> Shout out to my people A, G, C, and T!
>   All of your bases are belong to me!

Who am I?

Comment: Perhaps you mean "a couple of consonants" instead? I only see one vowel. :P

Comment: Um...You're right, hahaha.  In my head, 'D' was a vowel.  Will correct.

Comment: Honorable mention to U!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are

> DNA

I am an acid, found in all of your friends.
 I tell you how to look, but I don't make amends.

> The "A" in DNA stands for acid.  DNA is also found in everyone.

My man named Fred, he told you who I am.
 But no one understood me until I had an exam!

> Friedrich Meischer first discovered DNA, but it was not fully understood until Watson and Crick identified it.

I've got a couple of vowels to my name, for sure.
 But write me out the long way and you'll find a lot more.

> Deoxyribonucleic acid

Shout out to my people A, G, C, and T!
 All of your bases are belong to me!

> The four bases found in DNA are Adenine, Thymine, Guanine and Cytosine

Comment: Hah, that was easier than I anticipated.  :P  Will accept when it lets me. :)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a pretty widely known topic. I believe some would get it just from the title, many from the first line, and most by the letters listed.

Comment: Yeah, coming up with titles for rhyme riddles is annoyingly difficult, too.

Answer (score 3):

You are

> DNA

I am an acid, found in all of your friends.
I tell you how to look, but I don't make amends.

> DNA stands for Deoxyribonucleic acid and encodes near everything about us.

My man named Fred, he told you who I am.
But no one understood me until I had an exam!

> First discovered by Frederick Griffith.

I've got a couple of vowels to my name, for sure.
But write me out the long way and you'll find a lot more.

> Again DNA stands for Deoxyribonucleic acid.

Shout out to my people A, G, C, and T!
All of your bases are belong to me!

> A, G, C and T are 4 base pairs, with which the information is encoded in the DNA.

Comment: Haha, good job.  He beat you by mere seconds!

Comment: I did not type fast enough :)

Comment: You guys all blew me away with how fast you got it.  I should have spent more time trying to make it cryptic, but well done!

Answer (score 3):

> You are DNA

I am an acid, found in all of your friends.
I tell you how to look, but I don't make amends.

> DNA tells your body how to make you look

My man named Fred, he told you who I am.
But no one understood me until I had an exam!

> First found by Friedrich Miescher

I've got a couple of vowels to my name, for sure.
But write me out the long way and you'll find a lot more.

> Deoxyribonucleic acid

Shout out to my people A, G, C, and T!
All of your bases are belong to me!

> The four components of DNA